# What's more efficient for real time web apps, ajax or websockets?

Tags: django, ajax, websocket

I'm building a real time webapp with django.

The backend gets updated every 15min and I currently use ajax to update the template every 5min.

I'm planning on having 1000 users logged in at the same time, will ajax be enough?

I have been reading about django channels (Websockets) and I'm not sure how they will improve my webapp.

Comment: If you plan to create a real time chat or other things like that you might use WebSockets to open a socket one time, receive and send will be more efficient in this way than send an HTTP request by ajax.

Comment: If it's not time-critical (i.e. you're ok with your users seeing the change within 5 minutes), then by all means use ajax polling. Having 1000 concurrent open websockets is more resource intensive than processing 3.5 requests/second (the average if 1000 users make 1 request every 5 minutes). If it's real-time, like loic says, then websockets is the right way.